# How can I unescape and remove quot; from data served by rails into javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, highcharts

This question has been asked a few times on stackoverflow but I've yet to find a way how to unescape double quotes from a rails instance variable that I am trying to serve up in order for my highcharts to make use in my respective `js.erb` file.

Here is the code that I have:

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
  def foo
    @foo_bar = @foo.map { |f| f.version }
  end
end
```

The `@foo_bar` instance variable should return `["1.2.3","3.0","4.5"]`. Instead I keep getting this `[&quot;1.2.3&quot;, &quot;3.0quot;,quot;4.5quot]`; and I can't seem to remove this. I've tried using Rail's `escape_javascript` method but it still doesn't work. I've tried `JSON.parse(instance_variable)` and that didn't work either. Lastly, I tried to `.gsub` the quotes and manually replace them with `\"` and that didn't work either. Why won't the double quotes escape and how can I get this at the root of the problem? I've tried to solve this both server and client side but to no avail. Does anyone have anymore suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're inlining data that's being treated as HTML "unsafe", so you have to declare it as safe in your template.

```
<%= @foo_bar.to_json.html_safe %>
```

Note that when you declare something as "safe" that means you're confident you're not exposing yourself to XSS attacks because you're using some other escape method. In your case make sure you're emitting properly escaped JavaScript or JSON.

Comment: `.raw` is equivalent to `.to_s.html_safe` but as this is already a string by virtue of `to_json` it's not necessary. If you like the `.raw` notation, you can use that instead, but `.html_safe.raw` is overkill.

Comment: I'd stick with just `.html_safe` as you're doubling up on work otherwise.

Comment: @tadman, thanks for the speedy reply. Once I execute the `.to_json.html_safe` and the array becomes a string. Would I need to then reconstruct it into an array in my `js.erb` file?

Comment: If you're writing a JSON file the last thing you want to be doing is *parsing* JSON data.

Comment: Maybe I prematurely closed this question then.... Could you point me to an online resource that I could read up on this perhaps? What I want is to return my array object with strings in it so I can place the data in my highchart xAxis plot. It won't work with a string such as `"["2.3"]"`. I need `["2.3"]`. I definitely need to read up more on this.

Comment: You might want to use [Jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) to create a pure JSON view instead of dealing with all of this escaping stuff. Another option is `render(json: @foo_bar.to_json)` in your controller.